# yfinance shows a lot of null values

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I have managed to download stock data with yfinance for two tickers. However, for one of the tickers only shows the data for every 5 days instead of every day (see: [yfinance table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX8J7.png)). The other days all show a NaN value.

```
### download stock data
today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
my_tickers = df_main['ticker'].tolist()

df_stock_data = yf.download(my_tickers, start='2020-10-26', end=today)
df_stock_data
```

Comment: You have extracted the data correctly. If you go to yahoo finance, you can see that the data is indeed missing: [VUSA.AS historical data](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VUSA.AS/history?p=VUSA.AS)

Comment: I'm the same result. Isn't that brand only available in such a cycle?